# Git push hangs if there is nothing in refs/heads

Tags: git

There are many posts on SO about doing 'git push' on large repositories where you get an error like:

```
the remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

There are several reasons for that happening, but in my case I stopped it from happening by getting ssh to send a null packed to keep the ssh connection alive. I added this to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host *
 ServerAliveInterval 30
 ServerAliveCountMax 4
```

That stops the 'remote end hung upexpectedly' error, but what I see happening then is that git just sits there forever.

If I do a pstack on the running git process:

```
#13 lock_ref_for_update (err=0x7ffde40f2530, affected_refnames=0x7ffde40f23b0, head_ref=0xc979c0 "refs/heads/master", transaction=0xdd1ef0, update=0x1096e10, refs=0xc98c90) at refs/files-backend.c:2792
#14 files_transaction_commit (ref_store=<optimized out>, transaction=0xdd1ef0, err=0x7ffde40f2530) at refs/files-backend.c:2989
#15 0x00000000004606c9 in execute_commands_non_atomic (si=0x7ffde40f2560, commands=0xc98f80) at builtin/receive-pack.c:1357
#16 execute_commands (push_options=0x7ffde40f24e0, si=0x7ffde40f2560, unpacker_error=0x0, commands=0xc98f80) at builtin/receive-pack.c:1478
#17 cmd_receive_pack (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, prefix=<optimized out>) at builtin/receive-pack.c:1941
#18 0x000000000040600d in run_builtin (argv=0x7ffde40f2e60, argc=2, p=0x7e3e78 <commands+1944>) at git.c:371
#19 handle_builtin (argc=2, argv=0x7ffde40f2e60) at git.c:572
#20 0x0000000000406277 in run_argv (argv=0x7ffde40f2c20, argcp=0x7ffde40f2c2c) at git.c:624
#21 cmd_main (argc=2, argc@entry=3, argv=0x7ffde40f2e60, argv@entry=0x7ffde40f2e58) at git.c:701
#22 0x00000000004054bf in main (argc=3, argv=0x7ffde40f2e58) at common-main.c:43
```

The important line in the pstack is the first one '#13', it appears to be trying to lock 'refs/heads/master', but if I check my git repository:

```
[atlbitbucket@dubengvm494 fw]$ cd refs/heads
[atlbitbucket@dubengvm494 heads]$ ll
total 0
```

Is this a bug in git? (version 2.13) I would have thought it would say something like 'invalid git repository, no refs founds'. Instead it remains locked in this loop:

```
    while (1) {
            int was_alias = run_argv(&argc, &argv);
            if (errno != ENOENT)
                    break;
            if (was_alias) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Expansion of alias '%s' failed; "
                            "'%s' is not a git command\n",
                            cmd, argv[0]);
                    exit(1);
            }
            if (!done_help) {
                    cmd = argv[0] = help_unknown_cmd(cmd);
                    done_help = 1;
            } else
                    break;
    }
```

Comment: The refs can all be packed; in this case the directory can be empty. Git should still be able to lock them. If it gets stuck in an infinite loop trying to lock them, that would indeed be a bug... I assume you're tracing the Git at the server that is receiving the `git push`?

Comment: So I guess that 'git repack' packs the 'refs'? I did a 'git repack'. The server at the other end (Bit Bucket), says very little about what is happening. I have previously sent logs to Atlassian, and they said there was nothing of note in them.

Comment: It's `git pack-refs` that does that, but both get run by `git gc`. So you're tracing the client doing the push, not the server, here? The client should not need to lock the ref, just to read it. I'm not sure if the code locks anyway though.

Comment: Ah ok. yes, this is client side. I must do a 'pstack' on the server also, see what is happening there.

Comment: Correction! the code from above is server side, my apologies...

Comment: OK, so, the server shouldn't get stuck forever: the lock should eventually succeed. I'd have to have more info to debug it though.